# Is Pathfinder 2e compatible with Pathfinder 1e, and D&D 3.5 and 3rd edition?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, conversion, edition-comparison, pathfinder-2e

Pathfinder 1e was completely compatible with D&D 3.5 and to a lesser degree 3.0. Most mechanics and statistics can be used in the other systems without major modification.

Is Pathfinder 2e compatible with Pathfinder 1e, D&D 3.5 and D&D 3rd edition in the same way? If not how much work is currently needed to convert content?

Comment: I don't understand why this is attracting POB close votes. Whether or not the content is compatible is completely objective. And anyone who has attempted to convert material should be able to give a strong experienced based answer on how much work it takes.

Answer (score 15):

Mechanically, Pathfinder 2e is a completely different system. Even the things that share the same name are different enough that you can use basically nothing from 3.5e or Pathfinder beyond the ideas themselves—all the numbers, effects, conditions, costs, and so on are going to have to be redesigned from scratch for 2e.

Narratively, Pathfinder 2e has officially made Golarion the default setting, for better or worse, and of course it roughly captures a similar kind of magical fantasy world to those Pathfinder 1e was best suited to representing. So any narrative descriptions of setting content—particularly Golarion, but also really any other D&D setting—can be used with 2e about as well as they can with their original systems.

Comment: I think this answer would benefit from some detail, like whether the games use mostly the same concepts - hp, AC, level, stats, spells - and to the extent that yes, are the numbers on roughly the same range?

Comment: @Thanuir I answered that—no. Many of those terms are used, but used differently and with different numbers.

Comment: I took a look at a couple of random monsters, and stats (given that they are bonuses) and skills seemed fairly reasonable on a quick look, while attack bonuses and save bonuses were quite big. So a bit more detail would, at least for me, improve the answer.